# Google Data Studio: graph of sum(Event Value) by day

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

This seems like it would be so easy but I just can't figure it out. I want a simple bar chart showing me the event value of this event. Here's the result of 6 days of data, 1800 is the total value:

[image]

I just need a chart that gathers the sum of event value for each day and graphs it by day.

How can I do this?!!! I have lots of different custom events recorded in Analytics so I know I'll need to filter where Event Action = "Retention Emails Sent", but I can't sort out where/how to do that in Data Studio. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a bar chart to your report page in Data Studio. Add Date as Dimension, and Event Value as Metric. Then create a Bar Chart filter Include > Event Action Equal to (=) > Retention Emails Sent
[image: Data Studio Bar Chart Settings]

[image: Data Studio Bar Chart Filter]